# JavaScript/D3 - Create timeline bar chart with a generated dates range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have started discovering D3. I need to create a bar chart which takes a range of 20 middle dates between 2 dates (`this.startEndDateXAxis[0]` and `this.startEndDateXAxis[1]` in the demo) in bottom X axis, and 2 static values: **Actual** and **scheduleds** in the left Y axis.

Then we take a data set like this:

```
timelineData = [
  {
    type: 'Created',
    actualDate: '2023-08-30T11:15:02+0000',
    scheduledDate: '2023-08-30T11:15:02+0000',
  }
]
```

And display the 2 dates (`actualDate` and `scheduledDate`) on the X axis with a bar chart (just a 2px line, for example), `startDate` must be at height with **Actual** value and `scheduledDate` must be at height with `Scheduled` Y axis values.

Here is a playground demo: [Stackblitz playground demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-angular-4ec8ad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Observable Plot](https://observablehq.com/plot/?collection=%40observablehq%2Fplot) for this (built on D3)?

Comment: When answering the question, try to answer the proposed model first, before suggesting another library alternative